# How to import private key in PEM format using WinCrypt and C++?

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, cryptoapi, pem

I'm trying to use the [WinCrypt API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx) in C++.

My application need to cipher, decipher, sign and verify files, and I know how to do that once I have the correct keys. But my problem is actually that that is NOT the same application which generates those keys.

What I have is public and private keys in files in PEM format :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[Base64 encoded]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
[Base64 encoded]
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

After some research, I have found how to import the public key : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231178/load-an-x509-pem-file-into-windows-cryptoapi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573754/how-to-use-cryptoapi-and-cryptimportkey-with-a-asn-1-pem-openssl-public-key), using the following methods :

- **CreateFile** & **ReadFile** to read the file content
- **CryptStringToBinary**, with **CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER** to convert from PEM format to DER format (remove header and footer and decode from base64)
- **CryptDecodeObjectEx** with **X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO**
- **CryptImportPublicKeyInfo**, to import the key

But now, my problem is to do the same thing whith the **private key**.
Any help would be really really appreciated :)
Thank you.

Comment: Crypto API is for proprietary encryption, using it for PGP is just wierd

Comment: Yes, sure. But the fact is that I do not have the choice of the keys' format :/ Otherwise I would have chosen the proprietary format of CryptoAPI. But since the public key import is possible from PEM format, I thought that it would also be possible with a private key.

Answer (score 12):

A PEM private key can be imported into CAPI by using **CryptDecodeObjectEx** with **PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY** and then calling **CryptImportKey**.

I have written a sample that shows how to use a PEM encoded RSA private key for signing data using CAPI. Here is a link to it : http://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/capi_pem.cpp

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you Mounir.  YOu have saved me from a dead end.  (I was trying to get CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO without success, and I doubt that I need it).

Comment: Any ideas how to do the same with DSA keys?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem with an **encrypted** private key in PEM format. Here is the process I followed to decrypt and import it:

1. Decode the PEM using `CryptStringToBinaryA` with `CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER`
2. Decode the ASN.1 data using `CryptDecodeObject` with `PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING` and `PKCS_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO`

   - This produces some information about how the key is encrypted and the actual encrypted data. In my case, the key came from OpenSSL, and the encryption is described by [RFC 8018, Appendix A.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018#appendix-A.4).
   - I had to manually write some code to parse out this structure as it's not natively supported by `CryptDecodeObject`. You can find that code [here](https://gitlab.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-c-cpp/-/blob/master/src/lib/wincrypt.c).
3. Once you have the encryption of the private key and the information about how to derive the symmetric key and which algorithm to decrypt it (in my case PBKDF2 and AES-256-CBC):

   1. Use `BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2` to derive the encryption key from the password
   2. Use `BCryptDecrypt` to decrypt the private key using the symmetric key derived from the password.
4. Use `CryptDecodeObject` with `PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING` and `PKCS_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO`
5. Use `CryptDecodeObject` with `PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING` and `PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY` on the `PrivateKey` data member produced in the previous step.

The output of this last step is an [RSA Private Key BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/rsa-schannel-key-blobs#private-key-blobs). This can be imported with `BCryptImportKeyPair` and `LEGACY_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB`. Again, code demonstrating all of this can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-c-cpp/-/blob/master/src/lib/wincrypt.c).